# Implement messaging into website

Tags: chat, message-queue, messaging, message, livechat

I have a website where I have registered users in the system. When user logs into his profile I have section "Messages".

What is the best way to **implement messaging into the websit**e? I don't want to use plug-ins with live chat because of the pop-up boxes. I just want when one user will send a message to another, to have notification for new message, and to be able to start conversation between two sides in the real time.

I have an idea how to implement this with ajax, but I don't think it's a good idea to check for a new messages every a few seconds. Is there some better way to listening for a new messages and for **implementing messaging feature in the site**?

Comment: I am curious what you ended up using

Comment: I never actually implemeted this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A websocket is what you are looking for; however it is subject to some browser limitations and libraries may fall back to polling with Ajax if the browser doesn't support it.

Here is some reading for you so you can ask a more specific question in the future:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket (general info)
- http://socket.io/ (NodeJS and browser client library)